# Using txt file to delete user that is not shown in the list in linux debian10

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, script

I have an updated list of user in a txt file called updatedlist.txt, inside the list is all the existing username with some username being deleted as no longer needed, I want to write a script that can help me update the deleted user in my debian10 server. To make it clearer here is a rough pseudocode that I came out with:

for name in existing username
    if (name not in updatedlist.txt)
         remove user

sorry, i am very new to writing script can anyone teach me how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So you have list of users and remove users from current system who are not exist in that list?

Get user list of current system

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

But you don't want to remove bunch of system generated users. aka 'Sytem Users'. Normal users, that made from `useradd` command or any system management tools has UID between 1000 - 60000. `man login.defs`. Search for 'UID_MAX' and 'UID_MIN'.

```
getent passwd {1000..60000} |  cut -d: -f1
```

'{1000..60000}' <- this is shell specific expansion. bash and zsh should work. that command takes some time. about 30s?

Now we can save output to file

```
getent passwd {1000..60000} |  cut -d: -f1 > current.txt
```

We can compare 'shoulbe.txt' and 'current.txt'

```
comm <(sort shouldbe.txt) <(sort current.txt)
```

First column is unique to file1(shoulbe.txt)
Second one is unique to file2(current.txt)
Third one is both have

So column 1 should be blank not if you want make new user. Column 2 is what we should delete. Column 3 is what we should keep.

Double check outputs. Then read carefully `man userdel`. Find options you want. Like `--remove` for delete user's home directory.

Finally,

```
comm <(sort shouldbe.txt) <(sort current.txt) -1 -3
# double check this ouput. listed users would be deleted.
# then delete,
comm <(sort shouldbe.txt) <(sort current.txt) -1 -3 | sudo xargs -n 1 userdel(add your options here)
```

`-1`, `-3,` suppress that column. xargs part is run `userdel` on list one by one. `userdel` does not support multiple user names.

Be careful!